# How to send data between two clients

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, socketserver

I am making a simple game with multiplayer mode in it. I need to somehow send data between one player and other. I can't find a way to transfer data between two clients. Is there a way to forward them through the server?

I'm using the `socketserver` library to accept connections. Here is the way I handle connections.

```
def handle(self):
    data = self.request.recv(BUFFSIZE).decode("utf-8")
    print("Received connection")
    print(data)
```

Comment: You might be looking for https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: No, I am looking for a way to send data between two clients involving server, preferably not very hard way

Comment: maybe pub/sub messaging using Redis or 0MQ ?

Comment: Can you also mention your sever implentation?

Comment: I have already attached everything I had in my server implementation, what part of it do you need?

Answer (score 1):

From the 90s playbook: one of the clients can be a server; other clients (on the same LAN) connect to it.

It won't work well outside a LAN, because of NAT.

Normally you would need to run a dedicated server somewhere that would let users connect, and would route messages between them.

Naturally you would want to run all the game logic on the server, and leave to the clients only the display of state, and user input.

Also, a single server could host several games.

Implementation-wise, the socket server from standard library would be a good start; the HTTP server from the same standard library, an even easier start.

Comment: I have a dedicated server that hosts everything but I need a way to implement that message forwarding between clients

Comment: How does one client know which other client should receive the message? _Should_ it even care, or the server should instead? This depends on the design of your game.

Comment: Client sends the nickname and other person with that nickname should receive that data

Comment: So I'd make the server keep a map of nicknames and clients. Receive a message from client A intended to client B. Look up which client has nickname B, and send the message to that client.

Comment: I can't find a way to code that two clients will be connected at the same time and server will transfer data between them